# How to insert a static method in all classes using aspectJ?

Tags: java, android, aop, aspectj

for example, I want to insert a static method

```
public static void helloWorld() {
    return;
}
```

into the all classes of my project, how can I do?

Comment: ¿Do you want insert a static method into all your classes?, it seems strange. ¿Why don't create the static method in a public class and call it statically from your other classes?

Comment: I just test something. do you have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried AspectJ? It's supposed to work with Android AFAIK. Also, I found this link to be interesting: http://fernandocejas.com/2014/08/03/aspect-oriented-programming-in-android/

Comment: I'm trying aspectj, but it can't do this.